# C# Unity foreach loop exits early without break?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, foreach

I'm trying to count items (int id) in a list. Doing it so:

```cs
int currentId = -1;
int count = 0;
foreach (var item in rawItemList) {
    UnityEngine.Debug.LogFormat("Item {0}", item);
    if (currentId != item) {
        AddItem(currentId, count);
        count = 0;
    }
    currentId = item;
    count++;
    UnityEngine.Debug.LogFormat("Count {0}", count);
}
```

And here's the `AddItem` function:

```cs
void AddItem(int itemId, int count) {
    UnityEngine.Debug.LogFormat("Add item {0} count {1}", itemId, count);
    if (count == 0) return;
    items.Add(itemId);
    counts.Add(count);
}
```

`rawItemList`, `items` and `counts` are all `NativeList<int>`.

There are 7 elements in `rawItemList` - `{0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4}`. Printing those before and after above loop works fine (prints all the elements).

The issue I'm having is that after second `AddItem` call, the foreach loop exits, not even printing the rest of elements in `rawItemList`. Maybe worth mentioning, this code happens in a constructor. Is there a bug in here I'm not seeing?

Console log:

```
Item 0
Add item -1 count 0
Count 1
Item 0
Count 2
Item 2
Add item 0 count 2
Count 1
// Loop exits here
```

EDIT:
Just checked with standard for loop. Works fine this way. **What's wrong with foreach?**

EDIT 2:
Inserting full code. The last item is added outside of the loop.

```cs
// public struct CountedItemList ...

public NativeList<int> items;
public NativeList<int> counts;

public CountedItemList(NativeList<int> rawItemList) {
    items = new NativeList<int>(Allocator.Temp);
    counts = new NativeList<int>(Allocator.Temp);
    if (rawItemList.Length == 0) return;
    rawItemList.Sort();
    int currentId = -1;
    int count = 0;
    foreach (var item in rawItemList) {
        UnityEngine.Debug.LogFormat("Item {0}", item);
        if (currentId != item) {
            AddItem(currentId, count);
            count = 0;
        }
        currentId = item;
        count++;
        UnityEngine.Debug.LogFormat("Count {0}", count);
    }
    AddItem(currentId, count);
}
```

It's called like this from another script:

```cs
NativeList<int> rawItemList = new NativeList<int>(Allocator.Temp);

// Populate items

var cil = new CountedItemList(rawItemList);
rawItemList.Dispose();
```

EDIT 3:
In EDIT 1 I've replaced

```cs
foreach(var item in rawItemList) {
```

With

```cs
for(int i = 0; i < rawItemList.Length; i++ {
    int item = rawItemList[i];
```

The rest of the code stayed the same, yet the behavior changed.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Should be something else running on your machine and probably messing with the _rawItemList_. There is a problem though. The last item is not added to the items and counts lists.

Comment: Could you add more code context? Is it possible that one of the lists `items` or `count` by accident refers to the same as `rawItemList`? Do you get any errors? Have you tried debugging this with breakpoints step by step? ... And finally what exactly is your actual goal with this? It looks like you just want to create a dictionary for tracking how many elements of each value exist ...

Comment: Just like @Steve I can also not reproduce this ([.NET fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KMYITz) (fixed for not adding the `-1` item)) => something seems to either modify `rawItemsList` in the meantime or some exception happens

Comment: @Steve the last item is added after the loop.

Comment: @derHugo I've added more code. For even more context, the code is happening under Unity's ECS System, the 'rawItemList' is populated with Entities.ForEach counting items with specific tag. No parallelism, but Burst Compiler might be in use.

Comment: You add item quits if you dont have any items in the list. So it will never add any

Comment: @BugFinder the print sounds though as if at least 3 iterations are successfully done and logged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said pure logic wise I [can not reproduce this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KMYITz).

However, I implemented more or less exactly what you have in Unity like this

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    private CountedItemList cil;

    private void Start()
    {
        NativeList<int> rawItemList = new NativeList<int>(Allocator.Temp);

// Populate items
        rawItemList.Add(0);
        rawItemList.Add(0);
        rawItemList.Add(2);
        rawItemList.Add(2);
        rawItemList.Add(2);
        rawItemList.Add(3);
        rawItemList.Add(3);
        rawItemList.Add(4);

        cil = new CountedItemList(rawItemList);
        rawItemList.Dispose();
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        cil?.Dispose();
    }
}

public class CountedItemList : IDisposable
{
    public NativeList<int> items;
    public NativeList<int> counts;

    public CountedItemList(NativeList<int> rawItemList)
    {
        items = new NativeList<int>(Allocator.Temp);
        counts = new NativeList<int>(Allocator.Temp);

        if (rawItemList.Length == 0) return;

        rawItemList.Sort();

        var currentId = -1;
        var count = 0;

        //for(var i = 0; i < rawItemList.Length; i++)
        //{
        //    var item = rawItemList[i];
        foreach (var item in rawItemList)
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.LogFormat("Item {0}", item);
            if (currentId != item)
            {
                AddItem(currentId, count);
                count = 0;
            }

            currentId = item;
            count++;
            UnityEngine.Debug.LogFormat("Count {0}", count);
        }

        AddItem(currentId, count);
    }

    void AddItem(int itemId, int count)
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.LogFormat("Add item {0} count {1}", itemId, count);
        if (count == 0) return;
        items.Add(itemId);
        counts.Add(count);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        items.Dispose();
        counts.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Which results in a pretty not ignorable exception

```
ObjectDisposedException: The Unity.Collections.NativeList`1[System.Int32] has been deallocated, it is not allowed to access it
Unity.Collections.LowLevel.Unsafe.AtomicSafetyHandle.CheckReadAndThrowNoEarlyOut (Unity.Collections.LowLevel.Unsafe.AtomicSafetyHandle handle) (at <86acb61e0d2b4b36bc20af11093be9a5>:0)
Unity.Collections.NativeArray`1[T].CheckElementReadAccess (System.Int32 index) (at <86acb61e0d2b4b36bc20af11093be9a5>:0)
Unity.Collections.NativeArray`1[T].get_Item (System.Int32 index) (at <86acb61e0d2b4b36bc20af11093be9a5>:0)
Unity.Collections.NativeArray`1+Enumerator[T].get_Current () (at <86acb61e0d2b4b36bc20af11093be9a5>:0)
CountedItemList..ctor (Unity.Collections.NativeList`1[T] rawItemList) (at Assets/Scripts/ExamplePart.cs:24)
Test.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/Test.cs:24)
```

pointing to the line

```
foreach (var item in rawItemList)
```

I think the explanation is something like

The `NativeList<int>.GetEnumerator` used by `foreach` seems to be iterating asynchronously. You immediately do

```
var cil = new CountedItemList(rawItemList);
rawItemList.Dispose();
```

so the `rawItemList.Dispose();` seems to get called before the iteration via `foreach` is finished.

On the other hand `for` uses no special enumerator but synchronous index accesses so here it is ensured hat the constructor is finished before the list is diposed.

Comment: Strangely, I had no exceptions, probably because it was running with burst compiler. Your reproduction is pretty much accurate, so I think that was the problem in my case. Thanks!